# Show specific amount of items from String array list depending what the user chose

Tags: java

So in the code below i ask from the user first to enter some data and with pressing enter it goes to new line and writes the new one. If he writes END it shows him how many items they are stored and then he asks him again to choose from 1 to the list size of the items a number. After that i want to show him randomly some items depending the number he put. For example if he put 10 items at the first input and at the second he chose 5 to show him only 5 items randomly selected.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(
            "Δώστε στοιχεία προς κλήρωση (εισάγετε τα στοιχεία ένα ανά γραμμή - πατήστε ENTER για μετάβαση στην επόμενη γραμμή - πατήστε END για να λήξετε τη διαδικασία καταχώρησης)");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    while (!input.equals("END")) {
        list.add(input);
        input = scan.nextLine();

    }

    System.out.println("Καταχωρήσατε " + list.size() + " στοιχεία στη λίστα");

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
            "Πόσα στοιχεία θέλετε να κληρωθούν; " + "(εισάγετε ακέραιο αριθμό από 1 έως " + list.size() + " )");
    int user_num = scan2.nextInt();

    while (user_num == 0 || user_num > list.size()) {
        System.out.println("Eισάγετε ακέραιο αριθμό από 1 έως " + list.size());
        user_num = scan2.nextInt();
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println("Τα στοιχεία που κληρώθηκαν είναι:");
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

}
```

After the shuffling I print all the list items but i want only the items that the user chose that are saved in the variable user_num.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: After the shuffle it shows the user all the list items i want to show him only the ones he choose that is stored in user_num. If he choose the number 3 to show him 3 randomly list items from the list

Comment: Then use list.subList(0, user_num) and iterate over that sublist. Or break out of the loop after user_num iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (String word : list.subList(0,user_num) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Is this what you want? [subList](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-sublist-method-in-java-with-examples/) returns a new list with the elements specified by the indexes.

**EDIT:** to include index:

```
int index=1;
for (String word : list.subList(0,user_num) {
    System.out.println((index++) + ". " + word);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, do you know maybe how can i show them with numbers next to them? For example 1. george
                                     2. nick

Comment: it show me only 1. 
                          2. 
and nothing after the dot(.)